# How to preserve the page height when the content is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to preserve the current height of the page when doing an Ajax call. Almost the whole content is hidden before showing the new content, so the browser scrolls to the top of the page because there is no content below during the transition.

```
linksPages.on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'ajax' ,href : $(this).attr('href') }, function(response) {
            $('#content').fadeOut();           
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#content').html(response).fadeIn();
            }, 500);
        });
});
```

I thought about adding a class like:

```
linksPages.on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'ajax' ,href : $(this).attr('href') }, function(response) {
            //$('#content').fadeOut();
            $('#content').addClass('cortinaIn');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#content').html(response).fadeIn();
                $('#content').removeClass('cortinaIn');
                $('#content').addClass('cortinaOut');
            }, 500);
            $('#content').removeClass('cortinaOut');
        });
});
```

and define the `cortinaIn` and `cortinaOut` CSS rules:

```
.cortinaIn {
    transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform, -o-transform, -ms-transform;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform, -o-transform, -ms-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform, -o-transform, -ms-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform, -o-transform, -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transform:scale(0, 1);
    transform-origin: center center;
    -ms-transform:scale(0, 1); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform:scale(0, 1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -o-transform:scale(0, 1); /* Opera */
    -o-transform-origin: center center;
}
.cortinaOut {
    transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform, -o-transform, -ms-transform;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform, -o-transform, -ms-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform, -o-transform, -ms-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform, -o-transform, -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transform:scale(1, 1);
    transform-origin: center center;
    -ms-transform:scale(1, 1); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1, 1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -o-transform:scale(1, 1); /* Opera */
    -o-transform-origin: center center;
}
```

And this works fine, but I'm not able to find "fade in" and "face out" effects with CSS transforms. Any idea to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than you're making it.

```
linksPages.on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'ajax' ,href : $(this).attr('href') }, function(response) {
         $('#content').addClass('cortinaOut');
         setTimeout(function() {
             $('#content').removeClass('cortinaOut');
         }, 500);
    });
});
```

Then in your CSS, have this:

```
#content {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
}

.cortinaOut {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle showing what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/TUgr5/).

Answer (score 2):

using css `visibility:hidden` will hide the element (as if `opacity:0`) but will still take space and elements will flow around it, thus preserving the height of its container element.

Problem is that jQuery automatically does a display:block/display:none when using its fadeIn/out methods. I'd either use a jquery plugin (don't know one, but there are many) or directly use css3 transitions and roll your own function (most effective and efficient).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use `.animate()` method to change `visibility` but doesn't work. Finally I've chosen @knrz answer.